# Get array of data to object in angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

This is my old data that want to show in chart these work fine,

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app-inpout-bar-chart',
 templateUrl: './inpout-bar-chart.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./inpout-bar-chart.component.scss']
})
export class InpoutBarChartComponent implements OnInit {

saleData = [
{ name: 'Mozafati', value: 105000 },
{ name: 'piarom', value: 55000 },
{ name: 'rabbi', value: 15000 },
{ name: 'zahedi', value: 150000 },
{ name: 'Kalteh', value: 20000 }
];
constructor() { }
 ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Now I want set data from array to **saleData**

```
  productsName = ['Mozafati', 'piarom', 'rabbi' , 'zahadi', 'Kaliteh' ];
 productsValue = ['2000', '15000', '1500' , '5500', '10500' ]; 

 productData: any[] = [
  {name: this.productsName, value: this.productsValue}
  ];
```

but it's not work.
how can I set **ProductName** and **productValue** to ***Saledata***

**Update:**

after new comment and answer Updated to

```
export class InpoutBarChartComponent implements OnInit {

productsName = ['mozafati', 'piarom', 'rabbi' , 'zahedi', 'kaliteh' ];
productsValue = ['2000', '15000', '1500' , '5500', '10500' ];

//  productData: any[] = [
//     {name: this.productsName, value: this.productsValue}
//  ];
saleData: any[];

setData(){
 for (const i in this.productsName) {
  this.saleData.push({
    name: this.productsName[i],
    value: this.productsValue[i]
  });

 }
 }
//  saleData = [
//   { name: 'mozafati', value: 105000 },
//   { name: 'piarom', value: 55000 },
//   { name: 'rabbi', value: 15000 },
//   { name: 'zahedi', value: 150000 },
//   { name: 'kaliteh', value: 20000 }
// ];
constructor() { }

ngOnInit(): void {

this.setData();
console.log(this.saleData);
}
}
```

and my component.Html is

```
<ngx-charts-bar-vertical
[view]="[1000,400]"
[results]="saleData"
[xAxisLabel]="'product'"
[legendTitle]= "'number'"
[yAxisLabel]= "'value of product'"
[legend]="true"
[showXAxisLabel]="true"
[showYAxisLabel]="true"
[xAxis]="true"
[yAxis]="true"
[gradient]="true">
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
```

After add console.log I have this error

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Try `Array#map` method: `productsName = this.saleData.map(t => t['name'])` and `productsName = this.saleData.map(t => t['value'])`.

Comment: do you want to combine productsName and productsValue into saleData?

Comment: @Gabriel Bitencourt no, only I want to show data in chart separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set value 1-1 by arrays order (ex: `'Mozafati'` with `'2000'`), you can try:

```
productsName = ['Mozafati', 'piarom', 'rabbi' , 'zahadi', 'Kaliteh' ];
productsValue = ['2000', '15000', '1500' , '5500', '10500' ]; 

setData() {
    for (let i in this.productsName) {
        this.saleData.push({
            name: this.productsName[i],
            value: this.productsValue[i]
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Add this to `ngOnInit()` and let me see which is the result of `console.log()` : `ngOnInit(): void {
  this.setData(); console.log(this.saleData);}`

Comment: Sorry but does it really shows nothing with: `ngOnInit(): void {   this.setData(); console.log(this.saleData);}`?

Comment: Thank for your help and Update my question again

Comment: Opps, you have to set value for `saleData` first: `saleData: any[] = [];`. And `for (let i in this.productsName)`.